# What are the relevant hypothesis?

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

> Octopus Paul in 2010 predicted $8$ matches out of $8$ correctly during the football World Cup. Assume that Paul predicts the winner of a match with probability $p$, assume also that a match can not end with draw. You wish to investigate whether Paul has exceptional prediction abilities by using a statistical test, What are the relevant hypothesis?

1) $H_0:p=0.5$, $H_1:p>0.5$ 
2) $H_0:p<1$, $H_1:p=1$ 
3) $H_0:p=1$, $H_1:p<1$ 
4) $H_0:p>0.5$, $H_1:p=0.5$

I think that the correct one is number 4 because we investigate if the probability of prediction is higher that 0.5 (random selection) it's right?

Comment: Not quite: your question is whether Paul was special in some extreme way. Most octopuses (or octopodes) would be assumed to choose at random

Comment: So if we assume that he choose randomly it should be number one right?